# Child form in a mdi parent in C#

Tags: c#, winforms

I use the following codes for showing child form in a MDI parent form. As you know clicking the button will cause a new form to appear. Keep clicking the button and your screen will be filled with blank forms. To stop this from happening, I moved the code that creates the form outside of the button.

Like this:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    Form2 f2 = new Form2();    

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        f2.MdiParent = this;
        f2.Show();
    }
```

But when I close the child form and want to open it again, it won't let me.

Please help me to solve this.

Comment: `Form2 f2 = new Form2();` actually creates the instance, so if you let it out its only once and then won't be called again. Maybe what you need is `Hide()` when the closing event occurs and then again `Show()` it when you click

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to keep track of the form state so you know you need to create a new one.  Like this:

```
private Form2 f2;    

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (f2 == null) {
       f2 = new Form2();
       f2.MdiParent = this;
       f2.FormClosed += delegate { f2 = null; };
       f2.Show();
    }
    else {
       f2.Activate();
    }
}
```

Comment: That way you keep all your forms (mdichilds) as seperate variables (twice)

Comment: Is there a way to prevent child form to be shown when the other child form is already activated?

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to keep all your forms (twice) as variables. All mdi forms are added to your MdiChildren collection. So, you'd want to check if you need to show the form you've created.
Like so:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
    Form2 f2 = new Form2();
    f2.MdiParent = this; 
    OpenMdiChild(f2);
} 
private void OpenMdiChild(Form newForm)
{
    bool found = false;
    foreach (Form frm in this.MdiChildren)
    {
        if (frm.GetType() == newForm.GetType())
                {
                        frm.Activate();
                        frm.Focus();
                        //frm.BringToFront();
            found = true;
            break;
                }
    }
    if (!found)
    {
        frm.Show();
    }
}
```

If you want the users just to open 1 form, you could change the OpenMdi-- method to this:

```
private void OpenMdiChild(Form newForm) 
{ 
    bool found = (this.MdiChildren.Length > 0);  
    if (!found) 
    { 
        foreach (Form frm in this.MdiChildren) 
        { 
            if (frm.GetType() == newForm.GetType()) 
            { 
            frm.Activate(); 
                    frm.Focus(); 
                    //frm.BringToFront(); 
                    found = true; 
                break; 
                } 
        } 
    if (!found)
    {
            frm.Show(); 
    }
    } 
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for you help. But I got another question : Is there a way to prevent child form to be shown when the other child form is already activated?

Comment: I mean for example when child form2 is shown, prevent users to open child form3 or the other child forms till they close this currently child form then be able to open the other child forms.

Comment: Thanks. THAT'S ABSOLUTELY CORRECT. sry if i can't vote up cause i'm new and it is not gonna let me to vote up. THANKS