# working with MDI Form in VBnet 2010

Tags: vb.net, mdi

I have three forms

1. MDI form called Form Utama
2. windows form called formuser
3. Windows form called report

I have used menustrip to create menu.The menu strip contain:

1. form user (to call the formuser)

   code in menustrip is :

   dim Fuser as new formuser
      Fuser.MDIParent = me
      fuser.show()
2. Report ( to call form report )

   code in menustrip is :

   dim Rp as new report
      Rp.MDIParent = me
      Rp.show()

my question is

how to display the user form from the "MDI Form" but close or hide the report form, because when I use the above code, the MDI form have a lot of the same form as I call over and over - again

Comment: Can you not check the list of open forms in Application.OpenForms and close the forms you don't want or being to front if it already exists?

Comment: i try below code  formuser.hide() report.show() but is not working

Comment: possible duplicate of [Child form in a mdi parent in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10528547/child-form-in-a-mdi-parent-in-c-sharp)

Comment: DEar All, i already solve my problem by adding this code, and thank you guys for your advice.  http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/vbnet/threads/287586/closing-all-forms-within-mdi-parent-form

Answer (score 0):

here below is my program code when i run it all control button not working when i change the table name into comment everthing is working fine but if when remove the comment program not working and data table is shown in combo box

*

1. *here vch_trans table creating problem for me when i use it my control are not dis able at load and data not load into the combo
   box**

Public Class temp_vch
    Dim VCH_TRANS As DataTable

```
Dim vtype As DataTable
Dim credit_cust As DataTable
Dim debit_cust As DataTable


Dim bnd1 As BindingSource

Dim da As OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
Dim ds As DataSet
Dim cmd As OleDb.OleDbCommand


Dim debit_code_id As Integer = 0
Dim credit_code_id As Integer = 0
Dim vch_type_id As Integer = 0

Private Sub temp_vch_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load


    vtype = New DataTable("VCH_TYPE")
    credit_cust = New DataTable("CUST")
    debit_cust = New DataTable("CUST")

    VCH_TRANS = New DataTable("VCH_TRANS")




    proc_list.create_database_table("TRANS_TYPE", vtype)
    proc_list.create_database_table("CUST", credit_cust)
    proc_list.create_database_table("CUST", debit_cust)

    'proc_list.create_database_table("VCH_TRANS", VCH_TRANS)



    proc_list.fill_table(credit_cust, "CUST_NAME")
    proc_list.fill_table(debit_cust, "CUST_NAME")


    CREDIT_CMB.DataSource = credit_cust
    CREDIT_CMB.DisplayMember = "CUST_NAME"
    CREDIT_CMB.ValueMember = "CUST_ID"

    CREDIT_CMB.SelectedItem = "trans.CR_CUST_CODE"


    DEBIT_CMB.DataSource = debit_cust
    DEBIT_CMB.DisplayMember = "CUST_NAME"
    DEBIT_CMB.ValueMember = "CUST_ID"
    DEBIT_CMB.SelectedItem = "trans.DR_CUST_CODE"


    CMB_VTYPE.DataSource = vtype
    CMB_VTYPE.DisplayMember = "TT_TYPE"
    CMB_VTYPE.ValueMember = "TT_TYPE_ID"

    CMB_VTYPE.SelectedItem = "trans.vch_type"




    '        bnd1 = New BindingSource

    'ds = New DataSet
    'da = New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter

    'con.Open()

    'cmd = New OleDb.OleDbCommand("Select * from trans order by tdate", con)
    'cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
    'da.SelectCommand = cmd
    'con.Close()

    'ds.Clear()


    'da.Fill(ds, "TRANS")

    'bnd1.DataSource = ds
    'bnd1.DataMember = "TRANS"


    'VCH_TYPEID.DataBindings.Add(New Binding("TEXT", bnd1, "VCH_TYPE", True))
    'CR_ID.DataBindings.Add(New Binding("TEXT", bnd1, "CR_CUST_CODE", True))
    'DR_ID.DataBindings.Add(New Binding("TEXT", bnd1, "DR_CUST_CODE", True))

    'AMOUNT.DataBindings.Add(New Binding("TEXT", bnd1, "AMOUNT", True))
    'NARAT.DataBindings.Add(New Binding("TEXT", bnd1, "NARAT", True))

    'VCH_TYPEID.DataBindings.Add(New Binding("TEXT", bnd1, "VCH_TYPE", True))
    'mask_date.DataBindings.Add(New Binding("TEXT", bnd1, "TDATE", True))




    'CMB_VTYPE.DataBindings.Add(New Binding("selectedvalue", bnd1, "VCH_TYPE", True))
    'CREDIT_CMB.DataBindings.Add(New Binding("selectedvalue", bnd1, "CR_CUST_CODE", True))
    'DEBIT_CMB.DataBindings.Add(New Binding("selectedvalue", bnd1, "DR_CUST_CODE", True))


    proc_list.fill_text_autosource(CREDIT_AC, "CUST", "CUST_NAME")
    proc_list.fill_text_autosource(DEBIT_AC, "CUST", "CUST_NAME")


    AddHandler nevi1.add.Click, AddressOf addclick
    AddHandler nevi1.edit.Click, AddressOf addclick
    AddHandler nevi1.Reject.Click, AddressOf addclick
    AddHandler nevi1.delete.Click, AddressOf addclick
    AddHandler nevi1.bexit.Click, AddressOf addclick
    AddHandler nevi1.save.Click, AddressOf addclick

    AddHandler nevi1.bnext.Click, AddressOf addclick
    AddHandler nevi1.prev.Click, AddressOf addclick
    AddHandler nevi1.first.Click, AddressOf addclick
    AddHandler nevi1.last.Click, AddressOf addclick
    AddHandler nevi1.print.Click, AddressOf addclick
    AddHandler nevi1.excel.Click, AddressOf addclick


    proc_list.button_set("change_end", Me, nevi1)

    bnd1.MoveFirst()

End Sub

Private Sub addclick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal args As EventArgs) Handles nevi1.Click
    Me.nevigate_click()
End Sub

Sub nevigate_click()

    Select Case proc_list.nevi_btn_click
        Case "EXIT"
            Me.Close()

        Case "NEXT"
            bnd1.MoveNext()

        Case "PREV"
            bnd1.MovePrevious()

        Case "LAST"
            bnd1.MoveLast()
        Case "FIRST"
            bnd1.MoveFirst()

        Case "EXCEL"
            MsgBox("Not Working")
        Case "PRINT"
            MsgBox("Not Working")

        Case "ADD"

            proc_list.button_set("change_start", Me, nevi1)

            CREDIT_CMB.Visible = False
            DEBIT_CMB.Visible = False


            new_edit = "ADD"

            bnd1.EndEdit()
            bnd1.AddNew()
            CREDIT_AC.Text = ""
            DEBIT_AC.Text = ""

            CMB_VTYPE.Focus()
            Me.mask_date.Text = Now.Date


        Case "SAVE"

            vch_type_id = DirectCast(CMB_VTYPE.SelectedItem, DataRowView).Item("tt_type_id")

            Dim inst_text As String = ""
            Dim num_amount As Integer = Val(AMOUNT.Text)
            Dim book_type As String = "CB"
            Dim ts_date As Date = #2/13/2014#
            ts_date = DateValue(mask_date.Text)

            Select Case new_edit

                Case "ADD"

                    inst_text = "Insert into trans (CR_CUST_CODE, NARAT, AMOUNT, DR_CUST_CODE, REG_ID, VCH_TYPE, TDATE)"

                    inst_text = inst_text + " VALUES (credit_code_id, narat.text, num_amount, debit_code_id, BOOK_TYPE, VCH_TYPE_ID, TS_DATE)"


                    Dim ins_cmd As OleDb.OleDbCommand
                    ins_cmd = New OleDb.OleDbCommand(inst_text, con)
                    ins_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CR_CUST_CODE", credit_code_id)
                    ins_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NARAT", NARAT.Text)
                    ins_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AMOUNT", num_amount)
                    ins_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DR_CUST_CODE", debit_code_id)
                    ins_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@REG_ID", book_type)
                    ins_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@VCH_TYPE", vch_type_id)
                    ins_cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TDATE", ts_date)


                    ins_cmd.Connection = con

                    con.Open()
                    ins_cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                    con.Close()


                    MsgBox("TRANS SAVE ")

                    proc_list.button_set("change_end", Me, nevi1)
                    CREDIT_CMB.Visible = True
                    DEBIT_CMB.Visible = True

            End Select

    End Select


End Sub


Private Sub CREDIT_AC_Validated(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CREDIT_AC.Validated
    proc_list.FIND_CUST_DETAIL(CREDIT_AC.Text, "CUST_NAME")

    CR_CUST_NAME.Text = C_DET.CUST_NAME
    CR_OPEN_AMT.Text = C_DET.OPEN_BALAN
    CR_OPSIDE.Text = IIf(C_DET.OPEN_SIDE = 1, "CR", "DR")
    credit_code_id = C_DET.CUST_ID

End Sub


Private Sub DEBIT_AC_Validated(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles DEBIT_AC.Validated
    proc_list.FIND_CUST_DETAIL(DEBIT_AC.Text, "CUST_NAME")

    DEBT_AC.Text = C_DET.CUST_NAME
    DEBT_OPEN.Text = C_DET.OPEN_BALAN
    DEBT_OPSIDE.Text = IIf(C_DET.OPEN_SIDE = 1, "CR", "DR")
    debit_code_id = C_DET.CUST_ID

End Sub





Private Sub CMB_VTYPE_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CMB_VTYPE.SelectedIndexChanged
    'If proc_list.nevi_btn_click = "LOAD" Then

    'Else
    '    proc_list.COMBO_VAL_CHANGE(NARAT, VCH_TYPEID, CMB_VTYPE, "VCH_TYPE")

    'End If
End Sub

Private Sub CREDIT_CMB_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CREDIT_CMB.SelectedIndexChanged
    'If proc_list.nevi_btn_click = "LOAD" Then

    'Else
    '    proc_list.COMBO_VAL_CHANGE(NARAT, CR_ID, CREDIT_CMB, "CR_CUST_CODE")

    'End If
End Sub

Private Sub DEBIT_CMB_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles DEBIT_CMB.SelectedIndexChanged
    'If proc_list.nevi_btn_click = "LOAD" Then

    'Else
    '    proc_list.COMBO_VAL_CHANGE(NARAT, DR_ID, DEBIT_CMB, "DR_CUST_CODE")

    'End If
End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: if you want to ask a question... please post a separate question thread... don't open a question in another person's post...